# Laravel query join when empty

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying in vain to get a list of jobs that have no tasks assigned to them but I'm completely lost.

```
$jobs = Job::select( 'jobs.*' )
    ->where( 'is_active', '=', 1 )
    ->join( 'tasks', 'jobs.number', '=', 'tasks.job_number' )
    ->get();
```

This is doing the opposite of what i need and returning jobs that have tasks, further it is repeating the job for each task. So how can I get the jobs that have no tasks?

Comment: Could you add your jobs and tasks migrations?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `whereNull` clause for your query and change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

```
$jobs = Job::select( 'jobs.*' )
    ->where( 'is_active', '=', 1 )
    ->leftJoin( 'tasks', 'jobs.number', '=', 'tasks.job_number' )
    ->whereNull( 'tasks.job_number' )
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by reading the manual...

```
$jobs = Job::select( 'jobs.*' )
    ->where( 'is_active', '=', 1 )
    ->whereDoesntHave( 'tasks' )
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT jobs.*
FROM jobs
WHERE jobs.number NOT IN (SELECT job_number FROM tasks)
```

DB Facade

```
DB::table('jobs')
->select('jobs.*')
->whereIn('jobs.number',(function ($query) {
    $query->from('tasks')
        ->select('job_number');
}
->get();
```

Model

```
Job::select('jobs.*')
->whereIn('jobs.number',(function ($query) {
    $query->from('tasks')
        ->select('job_number');
}
->get();
```

Depending on how you defined your models (relationships) you could even use `whereDoesNotHave()`